# JavaScript code called once don't execute second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, hide

I don't think that is the appropriate title but I will explain here better.
I have an event that is happening on a click that shows a sticky footer on the bottom of the page. There you can see an HTML5 audio player and a close button. When I click the close button, nothing happens. No error in the browser console. 
Take a look at the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $(".playButton").click(function() {
    // Get the value of the button
    var val = $(this).val();

    // Paste the audio player
    $('#audioContainerBottom').html(show_audio_player(val));

    $('#navbarBottomFixed').show();

    audio_path = 'https://www.website.com/uploads/files/' + val;
    audio_core = $('#audio_core').attr('src', audio_path)[0];
    audio_core.play();

    $(this).hide();
    $(".stopButton").show();

  });


  $(".stopButton").click(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $('#navbarBottomFixed').hide();

    audio_path = 'https://www.website.com/uploads/files/' + val;
    audio_core = $('#audio_core').attr('src', audio_path)[0];
    audio_core.stop;

    $(".stopButton").hide();
    $(".playButton").show();

  });

  $(".closeBottomSidebar").click(function(e) {
    $('#navbarBottomFixed').hide();
    alert('Closed!');
  });

});




function show_audio_player(audio) {
  var src = 'https://www.website.com/uploads/files/' + audio;
  audio = '<div class="col-md-10 col-xs-10"><audio controls  id="audio_core"> ' +
    '<source id="audio_source_id" autoplay src="' + src + '" type="audio/mpeg">' +
    'Your browser does not support the audio element.' +
    '</audio></div>' +
    '<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">' +
    '<button class="btn btn-danger" id="closeBottomSidebar">' +
    '<i class="fa fa-remove"></i> Close </button></div>';

  return audio;
}
```

```css
.stopButton {
  display: none;
}

#playerContainer {
  display: none;
}

#navbarBottomFixed {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbarBottomFixed" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
  <div class="container" id="audioContainerBottom">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 'stop' is a function and you need to run it, `audio_core.stop()`

Comment: TypeError: audio_core.stop is not a function

Comment: You didn't understood my problem. The code works perfectly, the first two buttons work perfectly, but this code does not close the static bottom navbar:


$("#closeBottomSidebar").click(function(){
  $('#navbarBottomFixed').hide();
 });

Comment: Why do you even comment if you don't understand the code I have just passed?
When you press the Play button the code run this:  $('#navbarBottomFixed').show();

Comment: This: **.closeBottomSidebar** in your event handler declaration is different than this: **#closeBottomSidebar** in your HTML.

Comment: @RachelGallen if you saw in the code, the HTML is saved in a javascript function.
Once the button play is clicked it shows an audio player and a button that have the class of : closeBottomSidebar, there is my problem, when i click on the: closeBottomSidebar , the sidebar does not close. And the jQuery code is ok. No errors in console, nothing, but the sticky footer is still up.

Comment: @RandyCasburnI have fixed that, they are both pointing to the ID but still no response from the browser.

Comment: Great. Next, you are creating your audio player AFTER you set the listener. Each time you create a new player the listeners are not listening. You create a new player every time the play button is pushed. You have a classic race condtion with your listener set up.

Comment: I have made this video for you so you can understand better.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5I6ZtxHxMrM&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @xttrust your function to showaudioplayer is not enclosed inside the jquery open/close brackets

Comment: @RachelGallen, the result is the same.

Comment: I added the button on the page to try if i can close the sticky footer and it worked, but when I press the button that was called from JavaScript there is no response.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The close button is dynamically created by the `show_audio_player` function. It is not present on page load.

So the click handler here:

```
$(".closeBottomSidebar").click(function(e) {
  $('#navbarBottomFixed').hide();
  alert('Closed!');
});
```

is **not** registered because `$(".closeBottomSidebar")` returns no element.

The solution is to use [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$("#audioContainerBottom").on("click",".closeBottomSidebar",function(e) {
  $('#navbarBottomFixed').hide();
  alert('Closed!');
});
```

So the click handler is attached to `#audioContainerBottom` and delegates the event to `.closeBottomSidebar` if it exists at the time of the event... Even if it was not existing on page load.

Comment: Thank you very much. That was my problem.